# using SUM for objects stored in different segments

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I use the SUM function for objects that are stored in different segments (several records for one object). I try to order them by length using sum(length(t1.segments)) but get only one record as answer, i.e. the length of all the object in one. As soon as I try to include objects IDs in the query, I get an error.

```
SELECT sum(length(t1.segments)) AS length
FROM t1
```

Thats`working, here I get one answer (the lengths of all the objects segments).

```
SELECT t1.object_ID, sum(length(t1.segments)) AS length
FROM t1
ORDER BY length DESC
```

That`s not working any more. Even if I discard the ORDER BY part, just trying to include object IDs in the query, its not working.

Comment: If your second query is working, then I'm guessing that the underlying database is MySQL.

Comment: You have Postgis as a tag, are you talking about line segments, eg, from point 2 to point 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by` statement:

```
SELECT t1.object_ID, sum(length(t1.segments)) AS length
FROM t1
GROUP BY t1.object_ID
ORDER BY length DESC;
```

Comment: almost 4 questions now succefuly needs the answer of adding group by :)

Comment: @echo_Me . . . I'm always wondering about ways to automatically identify such questions.  The answers are really quite obvious to a human, but not so obvious to identify algorithmically.